# Cannot resolve No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-annotations

I'm trying to create Spring web application with annotations only(no configuration xml files). I am using tomcat as application server and maven for build the project. Googled a lot, modified a lot but still stuck with this error. Please find below the files. Hope some one can help me. Thanks in advance. :)

**Below is the pom.xml**

```
   <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Angular</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Angular Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.4.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-hibernate3</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>hibernate</artifactId>
                    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
                    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-commons-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-dao</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.8</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>3.2.3.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Angular</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

**the initializer file**

```
package com.sample.main;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;

import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

import com.sample.configuration.Configurations;
import com.sample.configuration.MvcConfigurations;

public class WebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

    public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext)
            throws ServletException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext rootContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        rootContext.register(Configurations.class);
        rootContext.refresh();

        servletContext.addListener(new ContextLoaderListener(rootContext));
        servletContext.setInitParameter("defaultHtmlEscape", "true");

        AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext mvcContext = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
        mvcContext.register(MvcConfigurations.class);
        mvcContext.refresh();

        ServletRegistration.Dynamic dispatcher = servletContext.addServlet(
                "dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(mvcContext));
        dispatcher.setLoadOnStartup(1);
        dispatcher.addMapping("/test/*");

    }

}
```

**The MVC configuration files**

```
package com.sample.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;


@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages={"com.sample.controller"})
public class MvcConfigurations {

    @Bean
    public InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver(){
        InternalResourceViewResolver resolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        resolver.setPrefix("/req/");
        resolver.setSuffix(".jsp");
        return resolver;
    }


}
```

** The root configuration **

```
package com.sample.configuration;

import java.util.Properties;

import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.sql.DataSource;

import org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.HibernateExceptionTranslator;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.Database;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect;
import org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.EnableTransactionManagement;


@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.sample.repo")
@ComponentScan("com.sample")
public class Configurations {

    @Bean
    public DataSource dataSource(){
        BasicDataSource basicDataSource = new BasicDataSource();
        basicDataSource.setUrl("jdbc:sqlserver://127.0.0.1:1433;databaseName=Garuda");
        basicDataSource.setUsername("sa");
        basicDataSource.setPassword("garuda123");
        basicDataSource.setDriverClassName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
        basicDataSource.setMaxActive(5);
        basicDataSource.setMinIdle(3);
        return basicDataSource;
    }

    /*@Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor persistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor(){
        PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor processor = new  PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
        return processor;
    }*/

    @Bean
    public HibernateExceptionTranslator hibernateExceptionTranslator(){
        HibernateExceptionTranslator exceptionTranslator = new HibernateExceptionTranslator();
        return exceptionTranslator;
    }

    @Bean
    public EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory(){
        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean bean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        bean.setDataSource(dataSource());
        bean.setPackagesToScan("com.sample.domain");
        HibernateJpaVendorAdapter jpaVendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        jpaVendorAdapter.setDatabase(Database.SQL_SERVER);
        //jpaVendorAdapter.setGenerateDdl(true);
        //jpaVendorAdapter.setShowSql(true);
        bean.setJpaDialect(new HibernateJpaDialect());
        bean.setJpaProperties(hibernateProperties());
        bean.setJpaVendorAdapter(jpaVendorAdapter);
        bean.afterPropertiesSet();
        return bean.getObject();
    }

    @Bean
    public JpaTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager jpaTransactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        jpaTransactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory());
        return jpaTransactionManager;
    }

    public Properties hibernateProperties(){
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "update");
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", "true");
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", "true");`enter code here`
        return  properties;
    }
}
```

**The controller file**

```
package com.sample.controller;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.sample.domain.Aircraft;
import com.sample.repo.AircraftRepo;
import com.sample.repo.MaintenanceCheckRepo;
import com.sample.vo.AircraftVO;

@Controller
public class MvcController {

    @Autowired
    AircraftRepo aircraftRepo;

    @Autowired
    MaintenanceCheckRepo maintenanceCheckRepo;

    @RequestMapping("/addAircraft")
    public ModelAndView addAircraft(@ModelAttribute AircraftVO aircraftVO) {
        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView();
        Aircraft aircraft = aircraftRepo.saveAndFlush(convertVOToEntity(aircraftVO));
        view.getModelMap().addAttribute("aircraftVO", convertEntityToVO(aircraft));
        view.setViewName("index");
        return view;
    }


    public Aircraft convertVOToEntity(AircraftVO aircraftVO){
        Aircraft aircraft = new Aircraft();
        aircraft.setAircraftRegistration(aircraftVO.getAircraftRegistration());
        aircraft.setAircraftSubType(null);
        return aircraft;
    }

    public AircraftVO convertEntityToVO(Aircraft aircraft){
        AircraftVO aircraftVO = new AircraftVO();
        aircraftVO.setAircraftRegistration(aircraft.getAircraftRegistration());
        aircraftVO.setAircraftSubtypeVO(null);
        aircraftVO.setId(aircraft.getId());
        return aircraftVO;
    }
}
```

**The repository**

```
package com.sample.repo;


import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;

import com.sample.domain.Aircraft;

public interface AircraftRepo extends JpaRepository<Aircraft,Long>{


}
```

**index.jsp**

```
<%@taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<html>
<body>
    <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    <form:form method="post" action="test/addAircraft"
        commandName="aircraftVO">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>Aircraft Reg No:</td>
                <td><form:input path="aircraftRegistration" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <input type="submit" value="Add Aircraft" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Web.xml**

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >

<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

**Adding stackTrace:**

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] in context with path [/Angular] threw exception [An exception occurred processing JSP page /index.jsp at line 5

2: <html>
3: <body>
4:  <h2>Hello World!</h2>
5:  <form:form method="post" action="test/addAircraft"
6:      commandName="aircraftVO">
7:      <table>
8:          <tr>

Stacktrace:] with root cause
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No WebApplicationContext found: no ContextLoaderListener registered?
at org.springframework.web.context.support.WebApplicationContextUtils.getRequiredWebApplicationContext(WebApplicationContextUtils.java:90)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(RequestContextUtils.java:85)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.RequestContext.initContext(RequestContext.java:209)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.initContext(JspAwareRequestContext.java:74)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.support.JspAwareRequestContext.<init>(JspAwareRequestContext.java:48)
at org.springframework.web.servlet.tags.RequestContextAwareTag.doStartTag(RequestContextAwareTag.java:77)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspx_meth_form_005fform_005f0(index_jsp.java:98)
at org.apache.jsp.index_jsp._jspService(index_jsp.java:65)
at org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:68)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:387)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:363)
at org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:306)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:304)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:240)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:203)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:164)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:108)
at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:558)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:379)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:242)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:259)
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:237)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:281)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662)
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what the problem is, but since you are using Spring 3.2, there is an easier way to bootstrap Spring with the Servlet environment. Check out this http://java.dzone.com/articles/getting-started-annotation

Comment: The full stack trace would be nice. Also, format your question.

Comment: For starters fix your spring version, you are mixing version 2.0.8, 3.2.1, 3.2.3, 3.2.4. Never mix versions of a framework. You also appear to be using an older version of Spring Data JPA with a newer version of Spring Data Commons. I would start with fixing the dependencies first. (Note Spring-hibernate3 and Spring-dao merged into Spring-ORM).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC
 "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.3//EN"
 "http://java.sun.com/dtd/web-app_2_3.dtd" >
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Your `web.xml` is wrong. You want to use a `ServletContainerInitializer` (the one provided by Spring) which is part of the servlet spec 3.0. However your web.xml makes the container operate in a 2.3 mode. Fix your web.xml.

```
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee 
      http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
      version="3.0">
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

Next, although not directly related but you will run into problems soon enough, you are mixing different versions of the Spring Framework. Never mix jars from different versions of a framework (not only spring but all frameworks). Tip use a single property to define the version you want to use.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mycompany.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>Angular</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.1</version>
    <name>Angular Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.2.9.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <spring.data.jpa.version>1.6.0.RELEASE</spring.data.jpa.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.data.jpa.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqljdbc4</artifactId>
            <version>4.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.10.Final</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>asm</artifactId>
                    <groupId>asm</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>Angular</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

I took the liberty to cleanup the pom and upgrade to the newest 3.2 version of Spring.

Answer (score 1):

Add the below tag to your **web.xml**, include it inside the `web-app` tag

```
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener
        </listener-class>
    </listener>
```